# How do I do this in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string `s` that's composed of random symbols and numbers that user types in.

Each letter ( uppercase or lowercase ) should be repeated the number of times indicated by the following digit.

```
%% 'x234'   - 'xx34'  
%% 'xx3333' - 'xxxx333' etc.

s = 'M2ab34*y2'
```

string `s1` should be:

```
s1='MMabbb4*yy'
```

I hope you get my point.

Comment: I think it can almost be guessed from your example what the algorithm is. But try to describe in prose, too. Maybe "Each letter or symbol should be repeated the number of times indicated by the following single digit number, or once if there is no number." Explain or show what should happen to "X234": "XX34" or "XX3333" ? In the second case use "...letter, digit, or symbol...". And may I recommend taking the [tour]?

Comment: Each letter (uppercase or lowercase) should be repeated the number of times indicated by the following digit. 
'x234' - 'xx34'
'xx3333' - 'xxxx333'
etc.

Comment: That is helpful information, good. It should be edited into the question instead of added in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for advice i will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html):

```
s = 'M2ab34*y2';
s1 = regexprep(s, '(\D)(\d)', '${repmat($1, [1 str2double($2)])}')

s1 =

MMabbb4*yy
```

The `'(\D)(\d)'` will match a single [non-numeric digit character](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#f0-42723) followed by a single [numeric digit character](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#f0-42723). Each character is captured in a [token](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#f0-42884) and subsequently passed to a [dynamic expression](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#btrv050) for the replacement string (which uses [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to replicate the character).

If you only want *letters* to be replicated (not symbols like `*`), you can use `'([a-zA-Z])(\d)'` for the match expression.